Universal Links with ASWebAuthenticationSession where prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession is set to false
I have an iOS app. I want to implement the social login with Notion. Using ASWebAuthenticationSession I could set up the whole flow using prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession set to true.
This is a bit inconvenient because the users would have to log in to Google to use the social login to then login to notion, and then finally to authorize my app to access their pages.
What I tried to do is set prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession to false which would allow me to open a browser view that could already have at least the login with google / notion and the Notion authorization page would show up immediately.
My issue is that using this setup, the Universal Link no longer redirects to my app. If I copy the same link and paste it in Safari I get the popup to open my app.
What am I missing, why are Universal Links not working in a session with prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession = false
